# Generate Default Silverlight Web Project After Project Already Created

Tags: silverlight

When you're creating a new Silverlight project, it asks you if you want to host the applicaiton in a new website and if you do so it generates a web project for you that's already setup and good to go.  If you chose no when initially creating your Silverlight project is there any way to automatically generate this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it automatically still, and it works in both VS2010 and VS2008.

Right click on the project file of your web app in the solution explorer, and select *Properties*. Go to the *Silverlight Applications* tab, click *Add*.

From this dialog you can either select an existing Silverlight app from your solution, or create a new one. Don't forget to tick the *Add a test page that references the control* checkbox.